# How to visit 3D Mat in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am using opencv c++ to calculate the histogram.

I have the following problem: I want to get a 3d histogram for RGB channels. I use the following code to get the 3D histogram:

```
const int channels[] = {0,1,2};
float rrange[] = {0,255};
float grange[] = {0,255};
float brange[] = {0,255};
int nbins[] = {4,4,4};
const float *ranges[] = {rrange,grange,brange};
Mat histMat; //4x4x4 3d histogram
calcHist(&orgimage,1,channels,Mat(),histMat,3,nbins,ranges,true,false);
int hist_array[] = new int[64];
hist_array = ?????
```

But I want to get a single dimensional array from hist, what should I do?

Comment: If I am getting your question right it might be a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473621/convert-opencv-matrix-into-vector

Comment: Everything is stored one dimensional in memory, there is a `data` member in [Mat](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Mat).

Comment: But how can I visit these elements in java? Is there any example?